# Where can I find Worklight Studio plug-in for IBM Worklight v5.0.0.3?

Tags: plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to find IBM Worklight Studio v5.0.0.3 (Eclipse plug-in).
The Eclipse Marketplace provides only the latest version (5.0.6).

It seems that IBM does not publically provide download of previous versions of IBM Worklight Studio (Eclipse plug-in).

I need to use specifically 5.0.0.3 as the server is the same version.
Does anyone knows where to find/download IBM Worklight Studio **v5.0.0.3**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eclipse marketplace version is the free Developer Edition. It runs completely within eclipse and there's no standalone Worklight server.

If you've install a separate Worklight server (on Liberty, WAS, or Tomcat)  then you're running the  Worklight Consumer or Worklight Enterprise edition and should use the studio plugin for that edition/version. As Idan mentioned, Business Partners can get the corresponding studio plugin from PartnerWorld.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't need studio unless I cannot get eclipse 5.0.0.3 plugin which suits my need.

Comment: Just to be more specific, I need it on the Mac OS X.
Using eclipse plugin seemed as the easiest option, but if at this point I need a studio it's not a problem to download.
I assume I need to download studio 5.0 and than install update for 5.0.0.3.
Thanks.

Comment: No, you only need to install the 5.0 base release and then upgrade to 5.0.0.3 if you are using the IM installer. If you are installing Worklight studio via eclipse P2 update then you can just install the latest CE or EE studio P2 update zip from IBM's FixCentral and install it using the archive option within eclipse.

Comment: Barbara / Idan, we are using Worklight free Developer Edition in development stage. The production will be running Worklight Consumer Edition 5.0.6. We are now setting up a new development machine (which matches the version 5.0.6 in production) and discover that the eclipse plugin is 6.0 currenctly... Is there any way to get the 5.0.6 eclipse plugin back? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Worklight Developer Edition installation:**

1.Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 (Java Platform, Enterprise Edition, or Classic).
The Worklight installation will fail if you are running a different version of Eclipse

Note: Java Platform Eclipse will be preferable.
Download Link : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR2/eclipse-java-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip

2.Supported operating systems: Mac OS X Lion 10.7 or Mountain Lion 10.8; Windows 7 or 8;    Linux Red Hat Workstation 6, Linux SUSE 11, or Ubuntu 12.04

Reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/install.html

3 IBM Worklight:

Install IBM Worklight Developer Edition
Download  iws_update_site_wde.version.zip  from
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/ add this  Archive file in eclipse

Install IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight (optional)
Download  mtww_update_site_wde.version.zip from
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/ add this archive file in eclipse.

4. Android

   ADT Plugin for eclipse: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
   SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Note: Install Android First then install IBM Worklight.

Further help : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34670/ibm-worklight-developer-phonegap

Comment: @ShashwatGupta Java adapters in WL will help.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have Worklight Server installed but not Worklight Studio, this implies to me that you are either a customer or partner of IBM (and have installed Worklight using the IBM Installation Manager).

- Customers can download past and current versions of Worklight via [IBM Passport Advantage](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/passportadvantage/).
- Partners should visit [IBM PartnerWorld](http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_home_pub_index).

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
I tried to find 5.0.3 through Access Catalog but got only 5.0.5 and 5.0.6.
We have 5.0.3 servers at client side and in local env.

Comment: Haven't used IBM Passport Advantage. I'll probably open a PMR and ask for the plugin.
Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Try this: http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_home_pub_index

Comment: Can you please delete this question(I don't have that option). Edited title and question does not match original meaning as I require developer eclipse plugin (the one Barbara stated as "free Developer Edition"), not studio plugin.
As for resolution I'll follow Barbara's advice and install a studio.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Save your time installing 5.0.3 especially if you are planning on using jQuery that comes with worklight native. 5.0.6 comes with 1.8.2 jQuery and has better native calls for worklight to save you time when you need to get usefull info and use the enhanced logging properties.

Trust me. If you you are not going to wait until 6.0 the use 5.0.6 and save yourself a lot of UI headaches.