# IBM Worklight wizard is not appearing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adt, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have installed `IBM worklight 6.0.0.2` in my eclipse `juno sr2`. I followed the steps which are defined by *RED.Skull* for the question **[Where can I find Worklight Studio plug-in for IBM Worklight v5.0.0.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649252/where-can-i-find-worklight-studio-plug-in-for-ibm-worklight-v5-0-0-3/18009502#18009502)**.

I could sucessfully installed the ADT and Worklight. When i start the eclipse IBM Worklight wizard is not appearing in the eclipse to create project.

I red and followed instructions given by IBM @ http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevenv%2Ft_extrastepsforrtcv4.0.html

But no change.

Answer (score 1):

You should really follow installation instructions based on the version of Worklight you are trying to install. Here are full installation instructions for Worklight studio for version 6.0.0.x:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevenv%2Ft_installing_ibm_worklight_studi.html

Here is a document that shows the system requirements for all of the different versions as well:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838

Also the Worklight Wizard for project creation does not appear on startup of Eclipse. In order to create a new Worklight Project, you must click File->New->Worklight Project. A dialog will then pop up and walk you through the necessary steps. You can find information on developing Worklight applications here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_devwlapps.html

Comment: Tnx Jaalger, i will try your suggestion and i will revert back.